# Spring: "class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0" [sic]

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) with Java 11 and Maven on [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). I'm trying create a JsonTset class as follows:

```java
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@JsonTest
public class JacksonInjectExample {

    private static final String filePath = "test.json";

    private static final String JSON = String.format(String.valueOf(Paths.get(filePath)));

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<OHStepTrackingNotification> jacksonTester;

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {...}

    @BeforeClass
    static public void setSystemProperties() throws IOException {...}

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {...}
}
```

But the build is failing on the below imports:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

It fails with the error:

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
  bad class file: /C:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.2/spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.class
    **class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0**
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I understand this problem is related to Java versions, but I can't find any working solution.

Using Java 11 which is set in JAVA_HOME.

What I have tried:

1. Update JDK to Java 11.
2. `java -version` gives: `openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 LTS`
3. Update the project in IntelliJ to work with Java 11.
4. Remove `.idea` folder.
5. Invalidate caches

How can I fix the confusing version?

Comment: [Spring Framework versions 6.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#overview) and later require Java 17. If your code must work with Java 11 you cannot use Spring Version 6.

Comment: Is there any way to use Spring Framework in lower java versions?

Comment: Use Spring 5 or older.

Comment: Spring Framework 5.3 is the latest version that can be used with Java 8 and Java 11. The (at the moment) latest release is 5.3.24: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.24/reference/html/overview.html#overview. Similar for Spring Boot: Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17. If you need to use Java 11 the latest usable version is Spring Boot 2.7 (2.7.5)

Comment: So according to  @Thomas Kläger upgrade to java 17 helps.

Comment: no images of plain text please

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You're using Spring Framework 6, and since Spring 6, the minimum supported Java version is Java 17 (the class version 61 is the class version of Java 17).

As documented in the [Spring Framework Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#overview) for Spring 6:

> As of Spring Framework 6.0, Spring requires Java 17+.

So, if you want to use Spring 6, you need to upgrade to Java 17. If you want to continue using Java 11, you need to downgrade to Spring 5.3.

Given Spring Boot 3 is built on Spring Framework 6, the same applies to Spring Boot 3: you need to upgrade to Java 17, or you need to downgrade to Spring Boot 2.7.

Comment: Same goes for Spring boot 3.x.x > it requires Java 17+

Answer (score 19):

To use version 11, if your project was created with version 17, change in [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F) adj reference image:

[image]

Comment: The mysql line doesn't mean anything here, also show the needed change in code blocks, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: when creating a project a spring version 3.0 project onwards and with java 17..
the mysql driver dependency is

    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>

so you should change the dependency so that you don't get an error to a previous version..

Comment: Latest version of spring-boot-starter-parent was 2.7.11 as of this writing: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: It has solved my issue when I degraded the project from java-17 and Spring-boot:3.1.0 to java-11 and Spring-boot: 2.7.0. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a text version. Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75326632/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it’s because of inconsistency between the Java version and the Spring or Spring Boot version. Check your version of Spring. Here is a snippet from the Spring site:

> We are planning to release Spring Boot 3.0 in November 2022. This next
> major revision will be based on Spring Framework 6.0 and will require
> Java 17 or above. It will also be the first version of Spring Boot
> that makes use of Jakarta EE 9 APIs (jakarta.*) instead of EE 8
> (javax.*).

From *[Preparing for Spring Boot 3.0](https://Preparing%20for%20Spring%20Boot%203.0*)*.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) and IntelliJ IDEA. So I did the following updates and it solved my problem.

1. *Preferences* → *Build,Execution,Deployment* → *Compiler* → *Java Compiler* (updated as 17)

   [image]
2. Preferences* → *Build,Execution,Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle* (updated Gradle JVM to Project SDK 17)

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, IntelliJ IDEA automatically uses Spring Boot 3.0 when creating a new Spring Boot project—even if you specify that it should use an incompatible Java version (i.e., earlier than Java 17). To use a 2.x version of Spring Boot, you will need to use the Spring Initializer:

https://start.spring.io/

You can then extract and load this into IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I was able to resolve it by redirecting to my .m2 directory present in C:\Users\Name.m2 and delete the repository folder.

Then open the project back in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), right click on project → *Maven*, and then → *Download sources and documentation*.

Answer (score 0):

If running from Eclipse (e.g. Maven commands), you need to be using the right JDK version for Run As -> Maven. Ensure that your JRE version is selected appropriately under the JRE tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct parent version as well!

I had the v3.0.5 parent version, and I still got this error. After I downgraded to v2.7.1, the error disappeared!

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had to work with Java 11 and got the same problem. It was solved by removing the "version" tag from:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked. JAVA_HOME on your machine could still be pointing to [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11), even if you changed it to [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17) in IntelliJ.

Here is what I followed:

1. Open a terminal and type in: `java --version`. If this gives you "java 11", that means you need to change the JAVA_HOME path to use Java 17 and not Java 11.
2. Go to IntelliJ: menu *File* → *Project Structure* (copy the JDK home path for Java 17)

   [image]
3. in the terminal: `export JAVA_HOME="<JDK home path>"`
4. in the terminal: `echo $JAVA_HOME` to verify if its set to Java 17
5. it should work for you now :)

Comment: Re *"gives you "java 11""*: It may give something like *"openjdk 11.0.21"* instead.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I deleted the path deployment, and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).