# How to solve the issue - "error: cannot find symbol import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage" - React Native?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

I am building a mobile app with React Native and I need to use both of modules - "react-native-gesture-handler" and "react-native-screens".

I installed those modules with `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens` and followed additional steps for Android.

But it fails to build APK.

Below is error log.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\projects\scannget-v2.1\scannget-mobile-v21\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
                                   ^
  symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
  location: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler
E:\projects\scannget-v2.1\scannget-mobile-v21\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
                              ^
  symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
  location: package com.swmansion.rnscreens
E:\projects\scannget-v2.1\scannget-mobile-v21\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
          ^
  symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
  location: class PackageList
E:\projects\scannget-v2.1\scannget-mobile-v21\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
      new RNScreensPackage(),
          ^
  symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
  location: class PackageList
4 errors
```

I searched everywhere regarding to this error but I couldn't find how to solve.

If anyone could help me, it will be much appreciated.

React Native version: 0.72.1
react-native-gesture-handler: 2.12.1
react-native-screens: 3.24.0

I could see that RNGestureHandlerPackage and RNScreensPackage were writte in Kotlin and I thought the issue was happened because Kotlin classes were not built.

I tried to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` into everywhere in build.gradle files but it still throws same error.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648576/spring-class-file-has-wrong-version-61-0-should-be-55-0) to resolve Your issue. I had a same issues with ***RNGestureHandlerPackage*** and other packages.

Basically it says, you should update ***JavaVersion*** from 11 to 17 in *app/build.gradle*

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same issue while working with my project, on figuring out the solution I tried to opt for another package instead of `react-native-gesture-handler` which was `@gg66/react-native-gesture-handler` which solved the issue but raised another error that the method `flushOperations()` was not found, then I tried to locate this method at `pathtoyourproject\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\src\handlers\gestureHandlerCommon.ts` with the code snippet

```scala
export function scheduleFlushOperations() {
    if (!flushOperationsScheduled) {
        flushOperationsScheduled = true;
        ghQueueMicrotask(() => {
           RNGestureHandlerModule.flushOperations();
    
          flushOperationsScheduled = false;
        });
```

after commenting the line `RNGestureHandlerModule.flushOperations();` the error was gone and I was able to continue with my project, unfortunately I don't know what might be the effect of commenting out that part.